# How to convert a list of numbers to date format in a data file with awk

Tags: awk, date

The second column are dates and I want it to be printed as DD.MM.YYYY. Please notice that the 4th line is a bit different.

```
89  150716  -50,00
101 170816  -50,00
123 141016  -100,00
142 91216   -100,00
19  140217  -100,00
38  230317  -50,00
50  200417  -50,00
65  260517  -50,00
77  190617  -50,00
95  200717  -50,00
106 150817  -50,00
120 150917  -50,00
164 171117  -100,00
10  150118  -100,00
```

Comment: See [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).   The only unambiguous date format.  It also sorts correctly.

Comment: @cas Interesting, didn't know this. Not surprising that Excel can't handle this. That's why I'm using awk to sort/process my lists.

Comment: I don't use Excel but I'd be very surprised if it couldn't format dates as YYYY-MM-DD.  It's been a common date format for a very long time, and it has long been known that it sorts correctly.

Comment: It can do YYYY-MM-DD but not YYYYMMDD or DDMMYY. I think I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 5):

```
awk '{ s = sprintf("%06d", $2); d = substr(s,1,2); m = substr(s,3,2); y = "20" substr(s,5,2); printf("%s%s%s.%s.%s%s%s%s", $1, OFS, m, d, y, OFS, $3, ORS) }' file.in
89 07.15.2016 -50,00
101 08.17.2016 -50,00
123 10.14.2016 -100,00
142 12.09.2016 -100,00
19 02.14.2017 -100,00
38 03.23.2017 -50,00
50 04.20.2017 -50,00
65 05.26.2017 -50,00
77 06.19.2017 -50,00
95 07.20.2017 -50,00
106 08.15.2017 -50,00
120 09.15.2017 -50,00
164 11.17.2017 -100,00
10 01.15.2018 -100,00
```

The `awk` code in a nicer form:

```
{
    s = sprintf("%06d", $2)

    d = substr(s,1,2)
    m = substr(s,3,2)
    y = "20" substr(s,5,2)

    printf("%s%s%s.%s.%s%s%s%s", $1, OFS, m, d, y, OFS, $3, ORS)
}
```

`s` is first set to the zero-filled six digit form of the second input field. `d`, `m` and `y` (day, month and year) are then extracted from this string and `20` is added as a prefix to the year part.

The `printf` then prints out the resulting record.  `OFS` is the current *output field separator* (usually a space), and `ORS` is the *output record separator* (usually a newline).

To get tab-separated output:

```
awk -vOFS='\t' '{ ...as above... }' file.in
```